# Regular expression Invert within Match

Tags: c#, regex

My string as follow

```
Data['5']=new Array('Jame', '54', '22', 'Dis')
```

My regex are as follow `(Data\[.+\])` will return me `Data['5']` , I understand that I can use the regex (\d+) and filter again to get the `5`  , but by doing that it incur of two time of use regular expression which I think is not a a good approach , and I am using C#.

Is that anyway that I could all combine the `(Data\[.+\])` and `(\d+)` , or any regex combination that allow me to get the number value inside the data like `Data['5']=new Array('Jame', '54', '22', 'Dis')` will return me a 5 .

Answer (score 1):

Use `Data\['(\d+)'\].*` pattern to capture group with index of data:

```
var s = "Data['5']=new Array('Jame', '54', '22', 'Dis')";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"Data\['(\d+)'\].*");
var index = match.Groups[1].Value; // 5
```

Comment: may I know why m.Groups[0] will return the entire string "Data['5']=new Array('Jame', '54', '22', 'Dis')" whereas  m.Groups[1] will only return 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use a look-behind, which is supported in C# Regex, if I remember right.

Your regex would be like:

```
(?<=(Data\['))\d+
```

This should pick out rows you want, and return only the number inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following pattern: `Data\['([0-9]+)'\]`. Your first match will then contain the number you're looking for.

As you said, there's no need to perform two matches. With the above pattern, you're not looking for any sequence of characters within the brackets (`.+`), but for digits only (`\d+`).

Comment: Note that in .NET, `\d` matches *unicode* digits, including unexpected ones such as arabic digits (e.g. ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩) - if that isn't desired use a plain `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: Also note that the type of the index seems to be a `char` because of the `'` around the 5. So, `[0-9]` is not appropriate here, I suppose.

Comment: @gehho The input is a string, as it always is with regular expressions. `'[0-9]+'` is perfectly fine to match one or more digits enclosed by a pair of single quotes.

Comment: @MariusSchulz Of course, it is. I was not talking about the index in the regex, but the index in the original string `Data['5']`. Here, `'5'` seems to be a `char` which is why the key between the brackets is not necessarily a digit. It could also be another character like `Data['b']` - and this would not be matched by the given regex. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: But I just saw that all the other answers are having the same problem because they are also using `\d`... Maybe it is just me, but I was wondering why it is `Data['5']` instead of `Data[5]`, so it might be relevant.

Comment: @gehho I have no idea where that piece of code is used, to me it looks like JavaScript. However, the answer is a correct solution to the question asked by *abc cba*.

Comment: @MariusSchulz Yes, sorry, you're right. Now I also realized that it is no C# code. Should have looked at it more closely...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=Data\[\')\d+
```